# environment with Eclipse PyDev PyClips...error on selecting a view from db

Tags: python, pydev

So I have this environment with Python 2.5, PyDev 2.5 installed, PyClips, and I have a sqlite3 database.
Looks like everything is fine and dandy until I run the following statement

```
  SQL = "select * from COMPLETE"
  cur.execute(SQL)
```

When I do this, eclipse throws the following error

```
cur.execute(SQL)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: COMPLETE
```

Where `COMPLETE` is a view in sqlite db.
Any ideas on why it is not seeing this view?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this. I created the view directly with a SQL statement in the code instead, and now seems to be 'seeing' it.